# Load RSS feed with PHP resulte in loading only part of the feed

Tags: php, curl, rss

I try to load and parse [feed](http://tokyotosho.info/rss.php?filter=1&entries=300&cat=1) with PHP. But when I'm loading it from PHP it contain only 40 [item] entries. I try to load it with cURL, or file_get_contents(). If I open feed in brouser, then save it local, then parse it - I have full numbers of [item]s.
What is the cause of the problem can be?

Example code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$xml_url = 'http://tokyotosho.info/rss.php?filter=1&entries=300&cat=1';    

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $xml_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru-RU; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050919 Firefox/1.0.7");

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$xml_data = simplexml_load_string($result);
```

Comment: They probably have some sort of limit imposed on their end when the reqeust is a curl instead of browser.  For obvious reasons.  Being that most RSS curl requests will be from mobile, so they want to limit the amount of data passed, and only pass the most recent and relevant info.  But it appears that the page has number amounts in the query string.  Have you tried including those headers in your CURL request?  ?filter=1&entries=300&cat=1  Like show us your CURL request.  thats the only way youll get any real help.

Comment: It would be good if you could provide an example of the code you're using.

Comment: Ok, I've added an example code.